# How to grep with spaces?

Tags: terminal, grep

I want to grep 500 error code from the log file

```
tail -f requests.log | egrep " 500 "
```

Its greping thing `hello500` or `500hello` or `hello500hello`

I only want to grep `500` with spaces around it, How can I do that?

Comment: Your `egrep` only matches `500` with spaces around it, see https://ideone.com/aIFFQl

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are mistaking, as you can see here:

```
Prompt>cat test_500.log
 a space with 500 space characters
hello500
hello500 with a 500 space
```

When I launch `egrep " 500 "` on this, this is what I get:

```
 a space with 500 space characters
hello500 with a 500 space
```

You can react "See, you also have the `hello500` result", but let me now show you the results, found by the grep, in bold:

a space with **500** space characters
hello500 with a **500** space

Grep returns the entire line. If there is a 500 between spaces in the same line of a "hello500", the "hello500" will be there too.